# "Attempt to write to null array" when adding properties to list

Tags: android, android-studio

i have an adapter that gets a list view , and i wanted to initialize it with lines,

it used to be written like this >

```
 arrayOfSplices = new AligmentListModel[] {
                new AligmentListModel("1", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "12", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "5", "0", "7", "0", "19"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "7", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "15", "99"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "7", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "13"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                new AligmentListModel("0", "456", "0", "0", "9", "0", "0")};
```

but now i want to move it to a for loop, 
iv'e tried to do this >

```
for (int i = 0; i < 18 ; i++) {
            arrayOfSplices[i] = new AligmentListModel("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1");
        }
```

but i get an error saying >

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
```

i'm inilizing my list in the create like this >

```
AligmentListModel[] arrayOfSplices
```

how do fix that error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rectifying a logcat error "Attempt to write to null array"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771439/rectifying-a-logcat-error-attempt-to-write-to-null-array)

Comment: @user2560571 you can use arraylist

Comment: @Dre it's not it's something diffrent, ive seen that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe initialize with

```
AligmentListModel[] arrayOfSplices = new AligmentListModel[18];
```

Comment: yea but i don't really know if my final size will be 18, maybe i'll add more later...

Comment: @user2560571 so its better to use arraylist instead of array.